# Can't get default account in OREO

Tags: android, accountmanager, android-8.0-oreo

In Android Oreo, `AccountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");` returns `null`.

Its, working fine in below Android 8 versions.

Below is my code:

```
private static Account getAccount(AccountManager accManager) {
    Account[] accounts = accManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    Account account;
    if (accounts.length > 0) {
        account = accounts[0];
    } else {
        account = null;
    }
    return account;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8.0 Oreo - Accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496069/android-8-0-oreo-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

As per Android's update, from Oreo onwards we can not use `AccountManager.getAccountsByType` to get the list of google accounts configured on user's device, as they have updated the Google SignIn features. The new feature will prompt the user to select the account and that account will be only visible to our app.

See the documentation: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#aaad

If you still want to continue with the old approach of showing all the account's to users, you need to get an extra consent from user by doing below procedures.

You can use `GoogleAuthUtil.requestGoogleAccountsAccess` to get the list of Google accounts.

A sample code is given below:

```
new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                GoogleAuthUtil.requestGoogleAccountsAccess(getApplicationContext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof UserRecoverableAuthException) {
                    startActivityForResult(((UserRecoverableAuthException) e).getIntent(),
                            REQ_CODE_PERMISSION_GET_GOOGLE_ACCOUNTS);
                } else {
                    Log.e("SignIn", "Exception in getting google accounts" + e);
                }
            }

        }).start();
```

This will create an activity to prompt user to accept the consent to allow Google Play Service to access the list of google accounts configured on the device.

You can then override `onActivityResult()` function on your activity to continue after.

Then you can use `AccountManager.getAccountsByType` to get the list of google accounts as you done before.

Happy Coding!