# Why don't I get my Google account with AccountManager?

Tags: java, android, google-tasks

I want to make a request for my Android application to display a Google Tasks task (in an AsyncTask).

```
public class TacheAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
private AsyncResponse delegate;
private Activity mActivity;
TacheAsyncTask(AsyncResponse asyncResponse, Activity activity) {
    this.delegate = asyncResponse;
    this.mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(mActivity);
    Account myAccount = accountManager.getAccounts()[0];
}
```

With the AccountManager, I only get my Samsung account (length of the request = 1), so I have no access to Google Tasks.

In my Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android:permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.app.notes.READ"/>
```

In my build.gradle (app) :

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

  implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:2.0.1'

  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

  implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.25.0'
  implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v1-rev155-1.25.0'
  implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
  implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-tasks:v1-rev49-1.23.0'
  implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:1.25.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am running into the same issue, and just posted a similar question on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087651/accountmanager-only-returning-one-account-in-extended-activity.).
I suspect that it is due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169680/cant-get-default-account-in-oreo) issue which affects all Android devices running Oreo. 
As described there you must use GoogleAuthUtil.requestGoogleAccountsAccess to get the list of Google accounts. Unfortunately that requires a non-blocking call to the service, and then using the completion of the background thread to trigger the Google account retrievals, which I am currently trying to work into my program.